# Memory issue with PHP

Tags: php, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm having some problem regarding memory with my app.

My app manage big xml from an api (something like 10 mb) that must be parsed and converted.

Sometimes, when multiple instance at same time program will crash caused of memory leaks.

I know that unset doesn't release memory but it will be moved to garbage collection but will it let it free eventually in case of needed?

```
<?php
function test() {
    $a = 100;
    $b = 200;
    $result = $a * $b;

    return $result;
}

function test2() {
    $a = 100;
    $b = 200;
    $result = $a * $b;
    unset($a);unset($b);
    return $result;
}
```

This will create any benefits in case of needed?

Comment: Probably not going to make much of a difference since $a and $b, as local variables, should be sent to garbage collection once the function terminates.  What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: How are you parsing the xml file? Are you using a memory-efficient pull parser like XMLReader?

Comment: I'm using SimpleXMLElement...

Comment: Yes it was just an example but in reality I'm using classes etc...

Comment: Using simpleXML loads the entire xml into PHP memory; you'd be better rewriting it to use XMLReader instead if you want to make it memory efficient

Comment: The real problem is not on xml, i'm sure it will use more memory the elaboration. It's a completely different format and to complete the elaboration php have to handle really big arrays with duplicated informations 10 times the xml itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using of SimpleXML. It loads the whole document to memory.

Use something SAX- like, for example XMLReader.

'Unset' you've  mentioned is useless. Let GC make the job.